# Axis2 error : Unable to add the following facets

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-axis, jboss5.x

I am trying to generate an axis2 webservice from a wsdl file in eclipse.
I am hitting this error message :

```
 Unable to add the following facetsto project AnnuaireAAAAAAAA: Axis2 Web Services Extensions, Axis2 Web Services Core.
    org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.FacetedProjectFrameworkException: Failed while installing Axis2 Web Services Core 1.1.
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.callDelegate(FacetedProject.java:1507)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.modifyInternal(FacetedProject.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.mergeChangesInternal(FacetedProject.java:1181)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.access$2(FacetedProject.java:1117)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject$1.run(FacetedProject.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.modify(FacetedProject.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.ui.common.FacetOperationDelegate$1.run(FacetOperationDelegate.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
    Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: The Axis2 facets cannot be installed since the Axis2 runtime location has not been set.
    Go to the Web Services preference page and set the Axis2 runtime location under Axis2 Preferences.
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.facet.deligate.Axis2CoreFacetInstallDelegate.execute(Axis2CoreFacetInstallDelegate.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.callDelegate(FacetedProject.java:1477)
    ... 8 more
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\DEV\axis2-1.4.1-war\webapp (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.core.utils.FileUtils.copy(FileUtils.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.core.utils.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.facet.utils.Axis2WebappUtils.copyAxis2War(Axis2WebappUtils.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.facet.commands.Axis2WebservicesServerCommand.executeOverride(Axis2WebservicesServerCommand.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.facet.deligate.Axis2CoreFacetInstallDelegate.execute(Axis2CoreFacetInstallDelegate.java:43)
    ... 9 more
```

Indeed, there is no webapp folder/file in C:DEV\axis2-1.4.1-war 
why am I hitting this issue ?
Thanks a lot for your answers.

EDIT :
Other error now :

```
Unable to add the follwing facets to project AnnuaireAAAAAAA: Axis2 Web Services Extensions, Axis2 Web Services Core.
    org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.FacetedProjectFrameworkException: Failed while installing Axis2 Web Services Core 1.1.
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.callDelegate(FacetedProject.java:1507)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.modifyInternal(FacetedProject.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.mergeChangesInternal(FacetedProject.java:1181)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.access$2(FacetedProject.java:1117)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject$1.run(FacetedProject.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.modify(FacetedProject.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.consumption.ui.common.FacetOperationDelegate$1.run(FacetOperationDelegate.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.DisabledResourceManager.save(DisabledResourceManager.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.DisabledResourceManager.disableValidation(DisabledResourceManager.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.wst.validation.ValidationFramework.disableValidation(ValidationFramework.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.facet.commands.Axis2WebservicesServerCommand.executeOverride(Axis2WebservicesServerCommand.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.facet.deligate.Axis2CoreFacetInstallDelegate.execute(Axis2CoreFacetInstallDelegate.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.callDelegate(FacetedProject.java:1477)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem today and I could solve it doing the following:

1. Download the Axis 2 binary distribution (link at the bottom)
2. Extract it
3. Enter **Eclipse** and go to **Window > Preferences > Web Services > Axis2 Preferences**
4. In the **Axis2 runtime location** field, points to your Axis2 installation directory (the one you created in step 2)
5. Click **Apply**
6. Close **Preferences** and try again

This worked for me. Remember that it is also necessary to install Axis2 **war** file in your Tomcat installation. [Link to all Axis2 packages](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.cgi).

Comment: link on step 2 broken

Comment: Removed the link. It was associated with the version of the package, so it was bound to break. Use the link at the bottom of the page to find the binary distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking in your project properties -> Project Facets page. When I manually try to add the facet 'Axis2 Web Services' I get a more descriptive error

```
The Axis2 facets cannot be installed since the Axis2 runtime location has not been set.

Go to the Web Services preference page and set the Axis2 runtime location under Axis2 Preferences
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to download and use the **binary** distribution of axis2 in your 'Eclipse Axis2 Preferences' (Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Web Services -> Axis2 Preferences -> Axis2 runtime location.
If you use the war distribution the Eclipse preference page won't show an error. But if you try do create a client out of a wsdl you get the shown error (I'm using Eclipse 3.7, I don't know how newer versions will behave).

Comment: This is important! However, one then bumps into the next error: 
Exception occurred during code generation for WSDL  : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchema   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchema cannot be found by org.apache.ant_1.9.4.v201504302020   - any ideas or workaround anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse expects your project to be `web` type. By this I mean if you use maven, it needs to be of `<type>war</type>`. If not, please add the details of eclipse project

Answer (score 0):

**Issue** : This is important! However, one then bumps into the next error: Exception occurred during code generation for WSDL : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchema Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchema cannot be found by org.apache.ant_1.9.4.v201504302020 - any ideas or workaround anyone?

**Solution** : I faced the same issue, seems like the issue got introduced from Axis2 1.7.0. Issue got resolved after i reverted to Axis2 1.6.0

Make sure you have done the below steps mentioned by marcelocra :

1. Download the Axis 2 war distribution (https://archive.apache.org/dist/axis/axis2/java/core/1.6.0/)
2. Enter Eclipse and go to Window > Preferences > Web Services > Axis2 Preferences
3. In the Axis2 runtime location field, points to your Axis2 installation directory (the one you created in step 2), Click Apply and Close Preferences.
4. Remember that it is also necessary to install Axis2 war file in your Tomcat installation. Link to all Axis2 packages.

Try now, This worked for us.